# How to invoke an AIR native installer app (EXE,DMG, etc) from browser

Tags: air, flash-builder, flex4.5

I'm looking at this Howto:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=distributing_apps_3.html#1036176

But I cannot get it to work with a Native installer application. These are .EXE/.DMG AIR apps that are downloaded and installed, NOT .air apps installed by badge.swf. I need to be able to do a browser invocation with a few additional flashvars set.

I already tried to modify the badge.swf file by got many compile errors in FlashBuilder 4.5

Is there an online example of how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The AIR installer badge is intended to be used in the situation where the user has Flash installed, but may not have AIR installed. When the user clicks on the badge to install the AIR application, the AIR runtime is first downloaded and installed if necessary, and then the application is installed.

There is no reason to use the badge with a packaged native installer because the installer will download and install the AIR runtime if necessary before installing the application.

You can create a SWF which looks like a badge and downloads the native installer using a [FileReference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html). There is however no way to execute the installer automatically after it has downloaded as doing so would present serious security risks.

The best course of action is to present clear instructions to the user on how to download and install the application using the native installer.

Comment: I understand that part. My question is different: assuming the native app is already installed, how do I launch it from the browser with some extra params like userid? The docs suggest that this is possible, but I can't seem to get it to work.